# Tesseract OCR on Windows Python

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I installed the Tesseract OCR engine and the `pytesseract` client library so that I can read strings that are contained in images. Regardless of which way I cut the cake, I get the following error. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pytesseract.image_to_string(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

Comment: So I understand the error. How do I fix it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not working.

Comment: What's not working? If the library is broken, raise an issue with the maintainers.

Comment: I installed it long ago, and it worked fine.

Comment: Now that I am using legitimately using it again, it crashes every time. I even tried editing the source of the library and I got nowhere.

Comment: It's unlikely it just magically stopped working, so... what *did* change?

Comment: I don't know. I tried reinstalling, and now it's prompting me to install it again and again as the program runs.

Comment: Then you need to contact the maintainers, SO can't give support with third-party tools.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here is an [image](http://snag.gy/tnVun.jpg) showing you that.